# Full-screen adaptive video

Tags: css

Trying to create full-screen adaptive video.

```
<video id='myVideo' autoplay>
    <source src='http://beardhouse.com.ua/wp-content/themes/beardhouse/sources/video/video-bg.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <source src='http://beardhouse.com.ua/wp-content/themes/beardhouse/sources/video/video-bg.ogg' type='video/webm'/>
</video>

#myVideo{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/udkt4/) what I have now, it takes all space of window but it's not adaptive.

How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with _adaptive_?

Comment: @putvande the video must be responsive to the size window of customers devise

Comment: Looks like it is already doing that.. what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by 'adaptive' ? do you want or not to keep the scale?

here

http://jsfiddle.net/udkt4/1/

i keep the scale/ratio and make it adjustable by width

```
#myVideo{
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```